# Does `gmp` library disregard index ordering in `[<-`?

Tags: r, indexing, gmp

Consider these two examples:

```
> foo <- 1:5
> foo2 <-  c(10,20)
> foo[3:2] <- foo2
> foo
[1]  1 20 10  4  5
> bar <- as.bigz(1:5)
> bar2 <- as.bigz(c(10,20))
> bar[3:2] <- bar2
> bar
Big Integer ('bigz') object of length 5:
[1] 1  10 20 4  5
```

Am I missing something in how `bigz` objects are indexed, or is this a bug in the library?

Added:  `gmp` 0.6.5 and R-windows 4.2.0 .

Comment: It is curious. I get your same result, whereas `bar
Big Integer ('bigz') object of length 5:
[1] 1  10 20 4  5`,  but `bar2 <- bar[c(1, 3:2, 4,5)]
> bar2
Big Integer ('bigz') object of length 5:
[1] 1  20 10 4  5 `, and of course `[.bigz*` exists.

Comment: I, on the other hand, was not able to reproduce the problem. My result is `> bar
Big Integer ('bigz') object of length 5: [1] 1  10 20 4  5` Strange...`packageVersion("gmp") [1] ‘0.6.5’`

Comment: It looks as though 'ordering' has to be attended to on the RHS, at least for greater than single assignments, which is unexpected. a_3=3,2,1 `a_3[1] <- as.bigz(100)
a_3
Big Integer ('bigz') object of length 3:
[1] 100 2   1` whereas `a_3[2:1] <- as.bigz(c(100, 200))` fails as above.

Comment: @guasi ?? You did reproduce my result, unless your replacement command was different.  Please check; thanks

Comment: Yes,  I was able to reproduce the problem. Don't know what I was expecting earlier when I said I couldn't reproduce it. Sorry. Very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received confirmation from one of the authors (M Maechler) that this is one of several bugs in  `gmp` related to indexing and subsetting.  There's also problems when attempting to run certain  `apply` functions, BTW.  We'll just have to wait for the next version to be released.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely irrelevant but viewed within a debug context on `[`

```
a_5 <- as.bigz(c(5,4,3,2,1))

a_5[2:3]
debugging in: `[.bigz`(a_5, 2:3)
debug at /home/chris/r_TMPDIR/RtmpVMOZqo/R.INSTALL4bd8b27ba6a92/gmp/R/biginteger.R#480: {
    mdrop <- missing(drop)
    Narg <- nargs() - (!mdrop)
    matrixAccess = Narg > 2
    has.j <- !missing(j)
    if (!is.null(attr(x, "nrow")) & matrixAccess) {
        .Call(matrix_get_at_z, x, i, j)
    }
    else {
        if (has.j) 
            stop("invalid vector subsetting")
        r <- .Call(biginteger_get_at, x, i)
        attr(r, "nrow") <- NULL
        r
    }
}
Browse[2]> Q
```

so we start in the context of `debugging in:` [.bigz`(a_5, 2:3)`,
our first `[`, whereas:

```
bar  = as.bigz(c(300, 400))
a_5[2:3] <- bar[2:1]
debugging in: `[.bigz`(bar, 2:1)
debug at /home/chris/r_TMPDIR/RtmpVMOZqo/R.INSTALL4bd8b27ba6a92/gmp/R/biginteger.R#480: {
    mdrop <- missing(drop)
    Narg <- nargs() - (!mdrop)
    matrixAccess = Narg > 2
    has.j <- !missing(j)
    if (!is.null(attr(x, "nrow")) & matrixAccess) {
        .Call(matrix_get_at_z, x, i, j)
    }
    else {
        if (has.j) 
            stop("invalid vector subsetting")
        r <- .Call(biginteger_get_at, x, i)
        attr(r, "nrow") <- NULL
        r
    }
}
```

and we're on RHS `debugging in:` [.bigz`(bar, 2:1)`, contrary to our expectation as would be with normal values:

```
a_norm <- c(5,4,3,2,1)
b_nums <- c(200, 300)
a_norm[2:3] = b_nums[2:1]
a_norm
[1]   5 300 200   2   1
```

where both the LHS 'where we want it' and RHS 'what it is' occur in a one liner. Note, I couldn't get debug to trigger in this instance.

Feature or flaw?

Comment: I've emailed the maintainer of the package; will report back if I get a resonse